# How do I get this header to span the page?

Tags: html, css, header

I want the black header to span the width of the page but I can't get it to. Here is my HTML:

```
<body>
  <div class="container_16">
    <header class="header grid_16">     
        <div class="grid_3 alpha">Ieesha</div>  
    </header>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
header { 
    background-color: black;
    height: 144px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.header {
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

If I change the .header width to 200% it will span the page but only from the start of the 960 grid and to the right.I have also tried using a 1px image and using background-repeat: repeat-x; but to no avail.

I have only been learning HTML & CSS for a couple of weeks so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: It is already warping full page! What do you want to archive?

Comment: It's only going to be 100% as wide as its containing element, which in this case is `<div class="container_16">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want it contained by `container-16`, take it out of there

```
<header class="header grid_16">     
 <div class="grid_3 alpha">Ieesha</div>  
</header>
<div class="container_16">
</div>
```

An example of your issue: http://jsfiddle.net/7cfc6mw2/

As you're learning here is a great tutorial on the [position property](http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/)

Comment: Thanks, the problem was to do with the container_16 class

Answer (score 1):

With the code samples you've provided, it works perfectly.  Look at styles for the parent elements and see if they're limiting your header's width.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the top of your CSS file:

```
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; }
```

This clears the default margin/padding/border settings of the page and will start your design at the same place in every browser.

If I misunderstood you, let me know.